# React GQL testing Error for MOCK PROVIDER

Tags: react-test-renderer

Invariant Violation: Expecting a parsed GraphQL document. Perhaps you need to wrap the query string in a "gql" tag? http://docs.apollostack.com/apollo-client/core.html#gql

[image]